# Problems with Liquid

Tags: mantaflow

I don't know if I checked a bad box or something but I was following mantaflow tutorials and now I cant get any liquid to flow out of an object marked inflow, I have the domain and an effector set but I cant get any flow out. Attached is the scene I'm working on if anyone can check it out and see what I'm missing, I'm trying to get liquid to flow out of a can[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tntq34yHzfB-lUuDEwLIwPNfJcRKzVkY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you have forgotten to bake your fluid. I baked your fluid and even though I saw no fluid (I only saw a blue ball appearing and dissapearing) there was still some animation data.

Comment: No I just unbaked it before I saved, The blue ball is all I'm getting too which looks to me like just a really large water particle, that's why I'm really confused

Comment: Ok so I got my answer from this      https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208713/how-to-decrease-the-size-of-particle-for-fluid-simulation2-9